# pass data as a parameter to action in test case cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, testing

i want to test a controller function getStructuredChartData which takes $chartData as a parameter

```
function getStructuredChartData($chartData = null) {
        $structuredChartData = array();
        $structuredChartData['Create'] = array();
        $structuredChartData['Create']['type'] = 'column';
        $structuredChartData['Create']['exportingEnabled'] = TRUE;

        if($chartData == null) {
            $structuredChartData['null'] = TRUE;
        } else {
            $structuredChartData['ChartParams'] = array();
            $structuredChartData['ChartParams']['renderTo'] = 'columnwrapper';
            ....
            ....
            ....
        }
}
```

and to test this the code i have written in testcase controller is as follows

```
public function testTrendsReportWithAjaxRequest() {
        $chartData = array();
        $from_date = new DateTime("2014-07-01");
        $to_date = new DateTime("2014-07-31");
        $chartData['StartDate'] = $from_date;
        $chartData['EndDate'] = $to_date;
        $chartData['View'] = "Daily";
        $chartData['Data'][(int) 0]['Project']['name'] = 'Test Project #1';
        $chartData['Data'][(int) 0][(int) 0] = array('reviewed' => '1', 'modified' => '2014-07-16');
        debug($chartData);
        // Invoke the index action.
    $result = $this->testAction(
            '/reports/getStructuredChartData',
            array('data' => $chartData)
    );

        debug($result);
        $this->assertNotEmpty($result);
}
```

now my concern is that how to pass $chartData to controller function in testCase.

Currently in Controller function $chartData occurs as NULL and the if condition

```
        if($chartData == null) {
            $structuredChartData['null'] = TRUE;
        }
```

gets executed. moreover i would like else condition

```
        else {
            $structuredChartData['ChartParams'] = array();
            $structuredChartData['ChartParams']['renderTo'] = 'columnwrapper';
            ....
            ....
            ....
        }
```

to be executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [CakePHP testing documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#simulating-get-requests)

> By supplying the data key, the request made to the controller will be POST. By default all requests will be POST requests. You can simulate a GET request by setting the method key:

You have to add get as method:

```
 $result = $this->testAction(
            '/reports/getStructuredChartData',
            array('data' => $chartData, 'method' => 'get')
    );
```

If you have your routes properly configured you can just pass the full url:

```
 $result = $this->testAction(
                '/reports/getStructuredChartData/test'
        );
```

Again from [CakePHP docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action)

```
// routes.php
Router::connect(
    '/reports/getStructuredData/:chartData', 
    array('controller' => 'reports', 'action' => 'getStructuredData'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('chartData'),
    )
);
```

Comment: This doesn't work.. by using this even i get $chartData as NULL in getStructuredChartData($chartData = null) method. instead what i used to get thing done is answered below..

Comment: hi @LuisClemente can you please explain what is 'test' in '/reports/getStructuredChartData/test' and how to know whether routes are properly configured or not..appreciate your efforts giving up vote...

Comment: @dipak1296 test is what your method expects ($chartData), check my updated answer for what is a properly configured method

Answer (score 1):

To pass $chartData as argument in TestCaseController what i did is ::

```
        $this->controller = new ReportsController();            
        $result = $this->controller->getStructuredChartData($chartData);
```